# El Método HTTP POST no es soportado por esta URL: IntellJ IDEA JSP Servlet, DAO Y VO

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hola tengo problemas con la ejecución de la web JSP de registrar usuario a la base de datos pero al ejecutar el programa con el servidor de JBOSS:

> El Método HTTP POST no es soportado por esta URL

Pero no entiendo el conflicto del post con el servlet

**Este es mi código HTML de registrousuario.jsp que envia con el metodo post y action"registerUser" al servlet con donde el servlet recibe con @WebServlet("/registerUser")**

```
    <section>
    <em>{0}</em>
    <form action="registerUser" method="post">
        <label for="documento">No. Documento: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Ingrese si numero de doucmento" required><br>
        <label for="nombre">Nombres: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombreusuario" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" required><br>
        <label for="apellido"></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="apellidousuario" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" required><br>
        <label for="clave"></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="claveusuario" id="clave" placeholder="Ingrese su clave" required><br>
        <label for="correo"></label><br>
        <input type="email" name="correousuario" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su correo" required><br>
        <label for="celular"></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="celularusuario" id="celular" placeholder="Ingrese su numero celular" required><br>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancelar"><input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
</section>
```

Este es el código de mi Servlet

```
     @WebServlet("/registerUser")
public class RegistraUsuarioServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String documento = req.getParameter("documento");
        String nombreusuario = req.getParameter("nombreusuario").toUpperCase();
        String apellidousuario = req.getParameter("apellidousuario").toUpperCase();
        String claveusuario = req.getParameter("claveusuario");
        String correousuario = req.getParameter("correousuario");
        String celularusuario  = req.getParameter("celularusuario");
        //recoleccion de datos
        Usuario usuarioVo =
                new Usuario(documento, nombreusuario, apellidousuario, claveusuario, correousuario, celularusuario);

        // call DAO layer and save the user object to DB
        UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        int rows = usuarioDAO.insertar(usuarioVo);


        // prepare an information message for user about the success or failure of the operation
        String infoMessage = null;
        if(rows==0){
            infoMessage="Sorry, an error occurred!";
        }
        else{
            infoMessage="User registered successfully!";
        }

        // write the message back to the page in client browser\
        String page = getHTMLString(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("registrousuario.jsp"), infoMessage);
        res.getWriter().write(page);


    }

    public String getHTMLString(String filePath, String message) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line="";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        String page = buffer.toString();

        page = MessageFormat.format(page, message);

        return page;


    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String page = getHTMLString(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("registrousuario.jsp"), "");
        resp.getWriter().write(page);
    }




    }
```

Código del archivo XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegistraUsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cartech.com.cartech.controlador.RegistraUsuarioServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>RegistraUsuarioServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registerUser</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**Imagenes:**

[image: WEB]

[image: Estructura de datos]

**Gracias por su atención**